# Sum entire pandas dataframe with different data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to create a function that will ignore sheets in my excel documents if no numbers are stored.

In my dataframe, there are both num and str columns. I only want to sum the number.

Here is my block:

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_workbook, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

output:

```
df = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Amount', 'amount2', 'Amount3', 'Percent total of gender', ['Mike', 'Male', 50, nan, 0, 0.20833333333333334], ['Nancy', 'Female', 30, nan, 0, 0.42857142857142855], ['Bob', 'Male', 100, nan, 0, 0.4166666666666667], ['Terrance', 'Male', 30, nan, 0, 0.125], ['Sara', 'Female', 40, nan, 0, 0.5714285714285714], ['Myo', 'Male', 60, nan, 0, 0.25]]
```

I've used this code to sum the df:

```
print(df.values.sum())
```

Which is giving me a typeerror:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming that you want to just sum all of the numeric values in the `list`'s of the ndarray

```py
import numpy as np

listOfLists = [x for x in df if type(x) == list]

goodType = [int, float]
SUM = sum([y for x in listOfLists for y in x if type(y) in goodType and ~np.isnan(y)])
```

Output: `312.0`

If you have values in the ndarray that are not in `list`'s that you also want to add to the total sum, then you can add the line at the end like:

```
SUM += sum([x for x in df if type(x) in goodType and ~np.isnan(x)])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, each sheet might be organized slightly differently. Once I create a list of sheets. I will pass to my other functions to begin cleaning the dataframes properly. I just can't figure out the right syntax to sum a ndarray while ignoring strings.

Comment: Will it always look similar to the above at least, where the first `x` strings values are the column names and then all of the rest are lists?

Comment: No, not in the raw dataframe. There are sometimes blank rows above the headers.

Comment: @MikeMann From what you told me (it's hard without access to your data obviously) this should work. It first creates a `list` of all the `list`'s in your ndarray. Then, it sums all the values together in those `list`'s given that the values are: `int`, `float`, and not `nan`. If there are values in your ndarray that are not in the `list`s (e.g. if "Gender" was actually a number and you wanted to add that to the total) then you can add the line in the second part that adds all values in the ndarray that are: int, float, and not nan.